# Upgraded Postgresql 9.1 to version 9.6- TCP/IP connections on port 5432? error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.6

I've upgraded from postgres version 9.1 to postgres 9.6 and i'm getting the following error when I try to connect to the database on the server:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

when I run pg_clusters it shows :

```
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

When I look in `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` it originally showed:

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5433                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

but I have now changed the port to 5432 but this doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. Is there another step(s) I need to take?

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart the service?

Comment: Ah, schoolboy error, cheers.